# Use Port 443 for both self hosted wcf service and IIS at the same time

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, ssl

I've got a self hosted WCF service, and an ASP .Net web site that need to run on the same machine.  I've discovered that when the self hosted service is running, all calls to port 443 intended for IIS (based on IP and host header/SSL bindings) get routed to the WCF architecture, and so the website stops working as long as the self hosted service is running.  It's effectively pre-empting IIS' ability to do it's job.

Note that IIS still works fine on other ports, like port 80.  It's just over-eager on port 443.  Not entirely sure whether this is a server issue or a code/wcf issue.

Comment: What type of binding are you doing? HTTP or net.tcp?

Comment: Http, a mix of webHttpBinding and basicHttpBinding.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use 443 for your wcf port? Can you use a port that is not in use? e.g. 8081

Comment: I have two concerns.  The first is whether or not all client machines will be able to access ports other than 80 and 443.  The second is that those WCF services are already active on another server, so I'm trying to migrate without having to update the client machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After quite a bit of research, I was able to determine that one of the service endpoints, a REST endpoint set to simulate a crossdomain.xml file was pre-empting IIS.  Otherwise everything was working as expected.  I ditched that endpoint and used IIS to serve the file instead.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds as though, as you suspect, the self-hosted service is intercepting calls to port 443 before IIS can pick them up. A quick check of your IIS logs should confirm if this is what is happening.

Be aware that although you can run multiple domains on port 80, if I recall correctly you can only use one on port 443, so things like host headers don't work with HTTPS connections. This could also be contributing to your problem.

Is there any way you could host the self-hosted service through IIS instead? That might solve this problem and reduce your administrative burden in future.

Edit following comments:
If you can't host in IIS then, assuming that I am correct that the WCF service is intercepting the requests for IIS and that is what is preventing the traffic getting through, then you may need to either add something to your WCF application or create ( or find an existing example of ) an independent proxy for incoming traffic based on HttpListener and use that to identify which service requests are looking for and relay it appropriately. Of course, this type of proxy service could also be used to mask extensions so you could use that to relay an external url of any format to the appropriate internal service url. The important thing is that the proxy sits ahead of both WCF and IIS in the network stack so it can intercept requests before they are picked up by either. If you are writing your own then [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx) would probably be a good starting point.

Comment: Hosting in IIS is not entirely out of the question, but I'm using extensionless URL endpoints in my service, e.g. /LSClient.  If I used IIS, I'd have to use /LSClient.svc, which would force me to update client code to reflect the new bindings.  This is non-trivial as I do not control the clients.

Comment: Also, the port 443 restriction is one application per ip/port combination I believe.  Even that can be gotten around by manually updating the IIS config to parse the host headers.

Comment: @GrantH : If you use the webapi then you would not have dependency on the .svc file and can get extensionless urls

Comment: @Rajesh, yes, but that would require new bindings, which means a client update.